# php: Из заданного текста выбрать и напечатать те символы, которые встречаются в нем ровно один раз (в том порядке, как они встречаются в тексте)

Tags: php, html

Впервые имею дело с php

Узнала, что для разбиения строк с помощью разделителя необходимо использовать функцию explode:

```
<?php
// Пример 1
$pizza  = "кусок1 кусок2 кусок3 кусок4 кусок5 кусок6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // кусок1
echo $pieces[1]; // кусок2
?>
```

А чтобы убрать повторяющиеся значения из массива, используем array_unique:

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>

Результат выполнения данного примера:
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

Для начала решила сделать ввод текста пользователем и разбить строку,но сейчас ввод текста есть, разбиения почему-то нет

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>help</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="decor" method="post">
  <div class="form-left-decoration"></div>
  <div class="form-right-decoration"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="form-inner">
    <h3>Введите текст</h3>
    <textarea placeholder="Текст" name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">


    <?php  
$input = $_POST['text']; 
$elem = explode(" ", $text);
echo $elem[0]; // это проверка чтобы ввывести первые 2 элемента text
echo $elem1[1]; // но они не выводятся
?>

  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Прошу вашей помощи в решении задачи(если можно, с комментариями)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это я ответ программы на ввод 1 2 3 3 при использовании кода ниже

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>help</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="decor" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div class="form-left-decoration"></div>
    <div class="form-right-decoration"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="form-inner">
        <h3>Введите текст</h3>
        <textarea placeholder="Текст" name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
    $input = $_POST['text'];
    $elem = explode(" ", $input);
    // собственно, решение:
    // преобразуем строку в массив
    $arrayAllInputSymbols = str_split($input);
    // избавимся от повторяющихся значений, поменяв местами ключи и значения полученного массива
    $invertInputSymbols = array_flip($arrayAllInputSymbols);
    // еще раз поменяем местами ключи и значения
    $uniqueInputSymbols = array_flip($invertInputSymbols);

    var_dump(array_flip(array_flip($uniqueInputSymbols)));

}

?>

    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А хотя бы какие-то идеи по нахождению уникальных символов есть?

Answer (score 0):

1 Для тега form укажите атрибут action;

2 Не путайте переменные $input и $text, $elem1 и $elem

3 Я невнимательно прочел задание и поспешил с ответом. Вот верный вариант.

```
if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
    $input = $_POST['text'];

    // получаем массив с количеством повторений символов
    $arrayAllInputSymbols = str_split($input);
    $numberSymbols = [];
    foreach ($arrayAllInputSymbols as $symbol) {
        if (empty( $numberSymbols[$symbol] )) {
            $numberSymbols[$symbol] = 0;
        }
        ++$numberSymbols[$symbol];
    }
    var_dump($numberSymbols);

    // отсеиваем результаты, количество повторений которых не равно 1
    $filteredSymbols = array_filter($numberSymbols, function ($symbol) {
        var_dump($symbol, $symbol === 1, '<br>');
        return $symbol === 1;
    });
    var_dump($filteredSymbols);

    // получаем искомый массив
    $result = array_keys($filteredSymbols);
    var_dump($result);



}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>help</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="decor" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div class="form-left-decoration"></div>
    <div class="form-right-decoration"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="form-inner">
        <h3>Введите текст</h3>
        <textarea placeholder="Текст" name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: если Вам необходимо выбрать и напечатать именно символы, зачем Вы получаете слова? не проще сразу разбить строку посимвольно?

Comment: И когда `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` становится равным `"><script>alert('42')</script><b` начинается магия.

Comment: )) согласен! но это отдельная тема. Ведь здесь не реальный проект?

Comment: только не $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], а $_POST['text']

Comment: Вот именно что `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Поэтому подставлять его бездумно в `action` нельзя.

Comment: может я чего не понимаю? в $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] хранится имя скрипта, верно? каким образом имя станет такого вида?

Comment: а главное - абсолютно бессмысленно, поскольку форма по умолчанию и так сабмитится на себя

Comment: ну по поводу бессмысленности - другое дело. а вот указанное Вами имя скрипта ставит меня в тупик.

Comment: запуталась немного что имеется ввиду в задаче

Comment: @ Yakoffka сейчас пробую ваш код(кроме вывода первых двух элементов), прикрепила к вопросу скриншот как это выводится, не работаем почему-то. Я ввожу 1 2 3 3. По идее должны быть выведены 1 и 2

Comment: @beartree не стоит сдавать этот код. Он, во-первых, неправильный, а во-вторых явно покажет что решение на 100% списано

Comment: действительно, я поспешил с ответом. исправил код. проверяйте.