# php: как проверить циклом есть ли в строке повторяющиеся элементы

Tags: php, html, css

как проверить циклом есть ли в строке повторяющиеся элементы, если элемент ни разу не повторялся, вывести его на экран

Сейчас мы вводим текст, разбиваем строку на элементы по пробелу, и выводим(для проверки) только первые 2 элемента, а нужно вывести те элементы, которые не повторяются(в порядке встречаемости их в тексте)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>help</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="decor" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div class="form-left-decoration"></div>
    <div class="form-right-decoration"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="form-inner">
        <h3>Введите текст</h3>
        <textarea placeholder="Текст" name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
    $input = $_POST['text'];
    $elem = explode(" ", $input);
    echo $elem[0] . "\n"; // это проверка чтобы вывести первые 2 элемента text
    echo $elem[1] . "\n"; 
}
?>

    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ??? разве здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1134599/php-%d0%98%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2 не приведено решение? или надо именно циклом?

Comment: там нет как-раз той части кода, где проверяем уникальные элементы и выводим их

Comment: да, действительно. поправил.

Answer (score 1):

с помощью `array_count_values` считаете сколько раз элемент встречается и фильтруете те где один раз.

```
$str = "a a z c c y x";
$data = explode(' ', $str);
$filtered = array_filter(array_count_values($data), function($v){ return $v == 1;});
$result = array_keys($filtered);
```

если надо именно циклом вручную, то пишите эквивалент для функции в виде

```
function xxx($data){
    $result = [];

    foreach($data as $k){
        if(!array_key_exists($k, $result)){
            $result[$k] = 0;
        }
        $result[$k]++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @beartree а вы точно сейчас не в ресторане?